# How to convert instagram post url to cover_url

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a javascript in which there is a function that takes the url form the text area in the description field and converts it into cover_url and cover_type to store it in database.. Here in this function it is doing that if we provide url for image or youtuve video or soundclub link it converts it into cover_url and cover_type and save it but I also that it takes url of Instagram post and save it in the form cover_type and cover_url.

```
var mtch="";
var matchtype=0;
function findimginpost() {
    desc= $('textarea#description').froalaEditor('html.get');
    desc=desc.split('>');
    var regexpimg1=/^<img[^>]+src=["|']{1}([^']*\.?[^']+)["|']{1}/i;
    var regexpimg2=/^<iframe[^>]+src=["|']?[^" & ^']+youtube[^" & ^']+["|']?/i;
    var regexpimg3=/https:\/\/.*soundcloud.*\/[^" | ^']+["|']?/i;
    var regexpimg=[regexpimg1,regexpimg2,regexpimg3];
    var type=['image','video','sound'];
    for(var j=0;j<type.length;j++){
        for (var i=0;i<desc.length;i++){
            desc[i]=desc[i].replace(/\"/g,"'");
            mtch=regexpimg[j].exec(desc[i]);
            if(mtch!=null){
                mtch+="";
                break;
            }
        }
        if(mtch!=null){
            mtch=mtch.split('src =');
            if(mtch.length<=1){
                mtch+="";
                mtch=mtch.split('src=');
            }
            if(j!=2)
            mtch=mtch[1];
            else
            mtch=mtch[0];
            mtch=mtch.replace(/"|'/g,"");
            matchtype=j+1
            if(j==0) {
                mtch = mtch.replace(/.*\//g, "");
            }

            if(j==1){
                mtch="https:"+mtch;
                mtch=mtch.replace(/watch\?/g,"embed/");
            }
            $('#cover_type').val(matchtype);
            $('#cover_url').val(mtch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cover_url and cover_type are strings values?

Comment: cover_url is string type and cover_type is integer type